# Remove duplicate entries from validation summary asp.net

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have a validation summary control on my page and my required field validators are in a list view. The listview can have any number of items, therefore I will have multiple validators with the same message. For example my list view could have 5 textboxes asking for a name, each textbox has a required field validator attached to it with the message "Please fill in your name". In my validation summary it shows 5 error messages all saying "Please fill in your name". How can I make it so that the validation summary shows one error with something like "Names are required".

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I may be wrong, but I guess you will need to do custom error handling in this scenario. ASP .NET validation controls AFAIK, does not provide this functionality. Take a look at these articles http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ze30x3t.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3w0bs977.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into using a [Custom Validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx). You can set the error message to "Names are required", and then in the custom validation check the status of each of your name fields. You can also wire up a Client side script with `ClientValidationFunction` as well.

Comment: Thought this might be the answer, was just checking if there was some other trick. Thanks